# Printing words common in two text files

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have two text files called dictionary.txt[file_dictionary](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I5_4iSATQZsBiazepkFOrcD2fm0EVU49) and output.txt[file_output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HKGw7bEEe2IcBfWXcahxc0crMDEZ42IH).Both of these files have three common words dance, sanct and test but I don't get anyword returned on comparing the two files:

```
with open('output.txt') as words_file:
with open('dictionary.txt') as dict_file:
    all_strings = set(map(str.strip, dict_file))
    words = set(map(str.strip, words_file))
    for word in all_strings.intersection(words):
        print(word)
```

I can't get what went wrong.Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python strings are case-sensitive. Strings in `output.txt` are upper-case, so you'll want to convert them to lower-case before doing the comparison:

```
# remove set from this line
words = map(str.strip, words_file)   

# convert list to lower-case, then apply set operation
words = set(map(str.lower, words))

# everything else same as before
for word in all_strings.intersection(words):
       ...
```

output:

```
dance
test
sanct
```